# Ozeki Voip SDK raises memory corrupt exception

Tags: c#, sip, voip, ozeki

I am testing `OZEKI VOIP SDK` in C# , I use their samples to test the reliability of the sdk. But after running for a couple of hours I get memory corrupt exception . the message is :
  `Attempted to read or write protected memory. this is often an indication that other memory is corrupt`

the test scenario is:
1- computer 1 : running an IVR that answers calls , waits 5 sec and hangups.
2- computer 2 : running an autodialer which sends 120 concurrent calls to computer 1.

has anyone tested the reliability of the SDK , or can help me to overcome the problem. 
any help is appreciated in advance

Comment: This sounds like dealing with unmanaged code incorrectly (not releasing handles ... - not in your code domain necessarily), why not go for [their support](http://www.voip-sip-sdk.com/p_26-request-support-for-ozeki-voip-sip-sdk-voip.html)?

Comment: I have already tried their support but unfortunately they don't have good support and don't give clear answers. and also reply to emails not very soon usually after 2 days. I found these problems after purchasing 128 channel license that's why I ask question here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is from SDK and nothing can be done.
I emailed their support and it seems that is a serious problem they can't solve.
I have purchased 128 concurrent channel license and using Ver 11.2.0.
No proper documentation is available and the SDK is not reliable.
After working for some hours the CPU goes 100% and no other call is answered anymore. 
I think the SDK is only for educational purposes and can't be used in products.